# CK Editor is giving me \n at the end of the string returned by getData

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ckeditor

I am using ckEditor in my angular based web widget and I dont know why it is providing me with "\n" appended string when I call the following.

```
CKEDITOR.instances['messageEdit'].getData();
```

For example the String is `"<p>Hello World</P>"`
The above code snippet is providing me `"<p>Hello World</P>\n"`

Can any body tell me whats happening with that ckeditor. Actually I need to do a string comparison so I need to remove that extra `"\n"`

Comment: Any one.... Any onee..... PLEASE !!!! :)

Comment: Do you mean that CKEditor appends new line character or literally two characters: "\n"?

Comment: Hallo? Is anybody there?! Why aren't you replying? It's 15 minutes already!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: There might be a difference in hours of your time and mine... so it was late at night..so I left for home...

Comment: Yes, it does append '\n' at the end of the string..

Comment: I dont know what exactly is... but when I perform getData, it adds '\n' at the end of the returned string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned on this link: 
[CKEditor documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_output_format), Try the following code:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {

    ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p',
    {
        breakAfterClose : false
    });

});
```

Comment: Mr. Jaffy: Thank you so much...!! Well I would prefer an asterisk '*' at the place of 'p'. So that it should work with all of the formatting tags of ckeditor.

Comment: Mr. Munneb Sharrif... I didnot said that he is wrong.. I said I would prefer.. 
(R.I.P English Language)!!!

Answer (score 3):

you can set this while configuring your Editor, in this way you can adjust settings of particular editor(if you have multiple editors on same page)

```
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        on: {
            instanceReady: function (ev) {
                this.dataProcessor.writer.setRules('p', {
                    breakAfterClose: false
                });
            }
        }
    });
```